# Blender renders are blotchy/noisy no matter what

Tags: rendering, denoise

Blender experts!

I've been doing an interior design render recently, and can't get rid of the blotchiness in my renders. It looks like this (just part of the render):
[image]

**The setting of the scene is as follows.**

**Lighting:**

- HDRI (3k) multiple importance + 7 area lights at windows pointing to the room used as "portals":
  [image]

**Render:**

- Cycles renderer, 300 samples, NLM denoiser (OptiX for some reason doesn't work with my GPU despite me having NVIDIA graphic card);
- Max bounces 6
- Shadows on for world and lighting

I was trying to play with light or HDRI brightness, samples number, etc., but my render comes out blotchy anyway. Sometimes it even doesn't denoise everything and comes out noisy + blotchy where denoised.
Unfortunately I can't for super high samples because I only have NVIDIA GTX 850M, so it will take me infinity to render each scene (which I don't have time for).

I was tying to follow some tips from different sources, including BlenderGuru, but they don't work much. Maybe it's a problem of lighting... I was making some smaller scenes with 250 samples, and they went out very fine.

I will be very grateful for any advice on this!

Best,
Dewr

Comment: When you say you followed blender guru's tricks, do you mean the "shadow ray/glossy ray shader trick"? If that doesn't work, is it possible to simply remove (some or all of) the windows completely? My guess is that the transparency from the windows is generating unnecessary caustics that are causing the denoiser to work overtime in areas it probably isn't really needed at all.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett , mostly I tried to work with clamp values and light bounce. But you might be right, I encountered several issues with windows in terms of light, so maybe I will try to remove them and see what happens. For now I substituted area light portals with emitting mesh (plane) and used Intel denoiser which does miracles... but not a definitive solution. Thank you for your suggestion.